# c : How to signal end of input

Tags: c, input, key-value

in this simple program that prompts users to input a polynomial,

I used int 999 as a value that represents end of input.

However, this is not a good design because users will not be able to input a polynomial node with a coeff of 999.

Is there an alternative key that can be unique to represent end of input?

**Relevant Code :**

```
int coeff;
int expon;
int i = 1;

printf("\nInput for polyNode %d  (999 for exit):",i);
printf("\n\tInput coeff : ");
scanf("%d",&coeff);

while(coeff != 999)
{
    printf("\tInput expon : ");
    scanf("%d",&expon);
    insertBack(&polynomial, &polynomialRear, coeff, expon);

    i++;
    printf("\nInput for polyNode %d  (EOF for exit):",i);
    printf("\n\tInput coeff : ");
    scanf("%d",&coeff);
}

printPoly(polynomial);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: No, You will have to use an integer value which can never be a coeff. If you can use strings then you can go for some particular string like "END"

Comment: Scan a string of characters, use a conversion to `int` if possible, else error or use a non-numeric string value to signify termination.

Comment: Why you __have__ to use same variable for main operation and looping? Just use a seperate loop control variable.

Comment: Would you considering asking first on the number of coefficients, and then loop for that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the return of scanf. If the scan is successful it will, in this case, return 1 for one item scanned. If the scan is unsuccessful, it will return either 0 or EOF. Input of any non-integer value (letters...) will end the `while ( 1)` loop.
Then clear the input stream with `getchar()` in a while loop.

```
int coeff;
int expon;
int i = 1;

while(1)
{
    printf("\nInput for polyNode %d :",i);
    printf("\n\tInput coeff : ");
    if ( ( scanf("%d",&coeff)) != 1) {
        break;
    }

    printf("\tInput expon : ");
    if ( ( scanf("%d",&expon)) != 1) {
        break;
    }

    insertBack(&polynomial, &polynomialRear, coeff, expon);

    i++;
}
while ( ( i = getchar ()) != '\n' && i != EOF) ;//clear input stream

printPoly(polynomial);
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait till end character will arrive, it maybe any symbol you wish (not a number, CRLF, TAB etc). After receiving of a complete input string do a processing.