# user entering zero to signal the end of input in C

Tags: c, arrays, input, io, scanf

Before you flag my question as duplicate, I've already been studying these similar questions and answers:

[c : How to signal end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543524/c-how-to-signal-end-of-input)

[Stop a for loop when user is finished entering input in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071321/stop-a-for-loop-when-user-is-finished-entering-input-in-c)

According to the above reference questions, my code should be correct but for some reason I cannot get it to break out of the loop and begin printing the output upon a user entered int such as zero or minus one.

For the record, this is a school assignment and I am not allowed to use 'fgets' for the time being, we are restricted only to using 'scanf'

I'm truly hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.  All I'm trying to do is have the user enter an unspecified number of ints and store them in an array.  I know the maximum number of values allowable which is why I'm using an array, however I want to give the user the option to signal the end of input by entering a zero or perhaps a minus one.  I know it should be exceedingly simple but try as I might I cannot get it to work unless the user enters a character.

My code is as follows:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int full_sequence[200] = {0};
int numElements = 0;

printf("enter sequence of integers: \n");


for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    if (scanf(" %d", &full_sequence[i]) ==0)
        break;
        //i've also tried setting i to the maximum index instead of using break, neither of which worked;
        else
        {
            scanf(" %d", &full_sequence[i]);
            numElements++;
        }   
    }

for (j = 0; j < numElements; j++)
{
    printf("\nend of input *********************");
    printf("\nArray element %d is: %d", j, full_sequence[j]);
    printf("\nthe number of non-zero elements is: %d", numElements);
}

return 0;
```

I've also tried replacing the for loop with a while loop and attempting to use negative one as the signal of the end of the input as follows:

```
while (testValue >= 0)
{
    scanf("%d", &testValue);

    scanf("%d", &full_sequence[i]);
    {
        i++;
        numElements++;
    }
```

Still nothing, the console appears to continue expecting input until I enter an alphabetic character, at which point the loop is finally exited and my output prints.  Oddly the scanf function only appears to be capturing every other number that I enter.

If I try to rewrite the for loop to also make use of a test value to validate the scanf item before adding it to my array similar to the way I had it in my while loop, it looks like the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &testValue);

        if (testValue == 0)
            break;
        else
        {
            scanf("%d", &full_sequence[i]);
            numElements++;
        }
    }
```

Still nothing.

Comment: I've also been told that scanf returns 1 when an item is correctly scanned so I could replace the if statement:  scanf(" %d", &full_sequence[i]) ==0)
 with something like scanf("%d", &full_sequence[i] != 1) however this also did not work.  I guess it raises the question, how do I refer to the int value stored at a given array index, versus the value returned to indicate the success of the scanf function itself?

Comment: Try and get into the habit of declaring your variables where they're used so the purpose of them is clear. For example: `for (int i = 0; ...)` instead of declaring `i` well in advance. This makes it clear what type `i` is, as well as where it's scoped.

Comment: @tadman good point, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t
#include <stdio.h>   // puts(), printf(), scanf()

enum { max_elements = 200 };  // don't use magic numers, give them a name

int main(void)
{
    int full_sequence[max_elements] = { 0 };
    size_t num_elements = 0;  // the type for sizes of objects in memory and
                              // indexes into them is size_t, not int

    puts("Enter sequence of integers:");

    for (size_t i = 0;
         i < max_elements  // as long as the current index is smaller than the size
         && scanf("%d", &full_sequence[i]) == 1  // an integer could sucessfully be read
         && full_sequence[i] != 0; // and the integer read is not 0
         ++i)  // increase the index
    {
        num_elements = i + 1;  // keep count of the number of elements
    }

    puts("\nEnd of input *********************\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
        printf("Array element %zu is: %d\n", i, full_sequence[i]);

    printf("\nThe number of non-zero elements is: %zu\n", num_elements);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, particularly for educating me on 'size_t' which I was unaware of.  Your answer has helped me immensely, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Since there’s another answer relevant to the coding end of things: the user traditionally signals end of input in a console program by typing the control code for end-of-file.  That’s control-D on UNIX, and therefore Linux and OS X, or control-Z on Windows (and its predecessors going back to the 8-bit era).

Comment: When `stdin` reaches `EOF`, `std::cin` becomes unusable.

Comment: @Swordfish And your answer correctly checks for both conditions (as well as filling the array).

Comment: Yes, I am just arguing against `EOF` as sole option to delimit input.

Comment: @Swordfish As you know, the traditional way to input with `cin` until end-of-file is `while (std::cin >> x)`, since the return value of the stream input operator is a stream (by reference) and a stream evaluates to Boolean `false` after encountering EOF.

Comment: Cant see your point `int foo; std::cin >> foo` not only fails for `EOF`.

Comment: @Swordfish Just that `cin` is veey usable with EOF (and there is a way to check that condition specifically if you need to). What other ways there should be to mark the end of input would be domain-specific.

Comment: Yes. And GScotts domain asks for input to end on `0`.

Comment: I don't think you got my point, though. After `EOF` `std::cin` will be useless for the rest of the program.